# Read .app wrappers app-info.plist file in Cocoa-Applescript project

Tags: macos, applescript

I want to access a keyValue which i have stored in the `.app` wrappers `app-info.plist` file, I am very much new to `AppleScript` and wanted to know how do i access the keyValue using `AppleScript`.

I want to access the said KeyValue ideally in

`on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)` in Delegate `AppleScript`

Attempted to execute shell script and get the path to the plist file, but failed. Any suggestions on how to go about this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily call the designated methods of NSBundle

```
set myValue to current application's NSBundle's mainBundle()'s objectForInfoDictionaryKey:"myKey" as text
```

If the value is not text, coerce it to the appropriate class

NSNumber -> `as integer`, `as real` or `as boolean`

NSArray -> `as list`

NSDictionary -> `as record`

NSData -> `as data`

NSDate (reference date 2001/1/1) cannot be used directly, it must be converted to an AppleScript date (reference date 1970/1/1)

Comment: Should this be casted as a Text or String for further usage ?

Comment: Yes, if it's text append `as text`, if it's an integer, append `as integer`, I edited the post

Comment: used plistbuddy in a shell command to get the necessary property, as the above answer didnt work for me

Comment: sorry to read that, I tested the code with several info.plist keys. Another way is to read the plist as NSDictionary `set bundlePath to current application's NSBundle's mainBundle()'s bundlePath()
      set infoPlist to bundlePath's stringByAppendingPathComponent:"Contents/Info.plist"
      set infoDictionary to current application's NSDictionary's dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:infoPlist
      set bundleIdentifier to infoDictionary's objectForKey:"CFBundleIdentifier" as text
      log bundleIdentifier`